# Jquery Submit method not working

Tags: jquery, html

i am using the sumbit() method in jquery but its not working for me.here is the code.
HTML

```
<form id="reg" action="process.php" method="post">
Username:<input type="text" name="name" size="25">

Password:<input type="password" name="ps1" id="ps1" size="25">

Confirm Password:<input type="password" name="ps2" id="ps2" size="25">
</br><span id="psmsg" class="msg">Passwords don't match!</span>

Contact:<input type="text" name="contact" size="25">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" id="register">

</form>
```

i am also using jquery to check whether the two entered passwords are equal or not.
Jquery code

```
$('#psmsg').hide();
$("#register").click(function (e) {
    alert('here1');
    e.preventDefault();

    if (($.trim($('#ps1').val())) != ($.trim($('#ps2').val()))) {
        isvalid = false;
        $('#ps1').css({
            "border": "1px solid red"
        });
        $('#ps2').css({
            "border": "1px solid red"
        });
        $('#psmsg').show();
    } else {
        $('#ps1').css({
            "border": ""
        });
        $('#ps2').css({
            "border": ""
        });
        $('#psmsg').hide();
        alert('here2');
        $('#reg').submit();
    });
}
});
```

The two alert messages 'here1' and 'here2' are being displayed but the form is not submitting to process.php as specified in action attribute.Any help?

Comment: try $('#reg').trigger("submit")

Comment: Try `$("#reg").submit()`.

Comment: Ankur, I have just checked your html and js code and for me it just works fine.

Answer (score 1):

As per your current code, `braces` are not closed properly.

try,

```
$('#psmsg').hide();
$("#register").click(function (e) {
    alert('here1');
    e.preventDefault();

    if (($.trim($('#ps1').val())) != ($.trim($('#ps2').val()))) {
        isvalid = false;
        $('#ps1').css({
            "border": "1px solid red"
        });
        $('#ps2').css({
            "border": "1px solid red"
        });
        $('#psmsg').show();
    } else {
        $('#ps1').css({
            "border": ""
        });
        $('#ps2').css({
            "border": ""
        });
        $('#psmsg').hide();
        alert('here2');
        $('#reg').submit();
    }
});
```